# VBA Excel For each / upper lower boundary

Tags: vba, ms-word, excel-2010

Im horrible at VBA but im on the verge of automating a good chunk of work of mine which would be roomreservations.

Rooms are in the column B5:B511, Dates are in E3:NF3. I can already return the column and row number of any cell that match the reservationnumber (string Listennummer in my case). The following things are missing:
[image: Excel]
In our example the reservation 140 has reserved 2 rooms, B5 & B9, from the 01.01-02.01 and 02.01-04.01

1. Return the date From E3:NF3, not the cell column/row -> done
2. Only return the first and last date of a reservation
3. Output into a word table with 3 Columns: Roomnumber, Start date, End date at certain point in document (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Startdate... etc) OR Tables.Add whichever is easier / less expensive

Output should be as follows:
[image: Desired output]
Input: 140

Output: Row A2: 1008, Row B2: 01.01, C2: 02.01.
Output: Row A3: 1012, Row B3: 02.01, C3: 04.01

Current output:

```
01.01.2024 
Roomnumber 1008
02.01.2024 
Roomnumber 1008
03.01.2024 
Roomnumber 1008
03.01.2024 
Roomnumber 1010
04.01.2024 
Roomnumber 1010
```

Code

```
Sub ConfirmationWithRooms()
Dim ListennummerFileName As String
Listennummer = InputBox("Bestätigung erstellen", "Reservationsbestätigung", "Listennummer eingeben")
On Error Resume Next
ListennummerCell = Worksheets("Bestätigung").Range("A3:A9999").Find(Listennummer).Address
If Err.Number = 91 Then
MsgBox "Listennummer existiert nicht"
GoTo Ender
End If


'Juicy Part

Worksheets("Kalender").Activate
Dim Rng As Range
Dim DateDayInterger As Integer
Dim DateOutputFloat As Date
Set Rng = Range("E4:I15")
Dim FindRng As Range
Set FindRng = Rng.Find(What:=Listennummer)
Dim FirstCell As String
Dim DateOfCell As String
Dim TowInteger As Integer
Dim RoomNumber As String
Dim RoomNumberInteger As Integer
FirstCell = FindRng.Address
OurYear = DateSerial(2024, 1, 1)
Do
Datedayinteger = FindRng.Column - 5
RoomNumberInteger = FindRng.Row - 5
DateOutputFloat = OurYear + Datedayinteger
RoomNumber = Range("B5").Offset(RoomNumberInteger, 0)
Debug.Print DateOutputFloat
Debug.Print "Roomnumber " & RoomNumber
  Set FindRng = Rng.FindNext(FindRng)
  Loop While FirstCell <> FindRng.Address

'End juicy part

Set Wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    Wordapp.Documents.Open "M:\Teams\ReservationWord.docx"
    Wordapp.Visible = True
    Wordapp.Activate
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
'Can throw errors without Wait
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Listennummer").Range.Text = Listennummer
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BestellerEmail").Range.Text = BestellerEmail
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BestellerName").Range.Text = BestellerName
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BestellerTelefon").Range.Text = BestellerTelefon
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bestelltam").Range.Text = Bestelltam
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BestelltfuerName").Range.Text = BestelltfuerName
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BestelltfuerEmail").Range.Text = BestelltfuerEmail
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BestelltfuerTelefon").Range.Text = BestelltfuerTelefon
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bestelltvia").Range.Text = Bestelltvia
'Tables.Add?
Ender:
End Sub
```

Comment: Your post probably is too broad - it would be best to focus on one aspect of the process, such as getting a list of all the room/start/end rows you'll need for the Word doc.

Comment: Info: Dates are always stored as `Double` floating point numbers in Excel, and only the displaying  is date in one of the defined formats.

Comment: To add it to a `Word` document, the idea is to create the table in the desired look on an empty new Sheet. Write the Word document, and where you want to place the table of the result, create a link or embed the Excel sheet, depending on that, if a continuous update is necessary or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea for the first part - it loops over the entire dataset, but it's fast because it's looping over an array and not cell-by-cell on the worksheet.

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    Dim arr, r As Long, c As Long, col As New Collection, v, dt
    Dim resNum, inRes As Boolean, arrRes, ubr As Long, ubc As Long
    
    resNum = 140 'for example
    
    'read all the data, including dates and room numbers
    arr = Worksheets("Kalender").Range("B3:NF511").Value
    ubc = UBound(arr, 2) 'column upper bound
    
    'loop over the main data...
    For r = 3 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For c = 4 To ubc
            v = arr(r, c)         'res number if any
            If v = resNum Then    'the one we're looking for?
                If Not inRes Then 'starting a reservation?
                    arrRes = Array(arr(r, 1), arr(1, c), "null") 'record room number and start date
                    inRes = True  'set flag
                End If
            End If
            'have run out of the reservation, or we're at end of a row?
            If v <> resNum Or c = ubc Then
                If inRes Then
                    arrRes(2) = IIf(c = ubc, arr(1, c), arr(1, c - 1)) 'end date
                    col.Add arrRes  'add to collection
                    inRes = False   'clear flag
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    If col.Count > 0 Then
        For Each v In col
            Debug.Print Join(v, vbTab)  'print details
        Next v
    Else
        MsgBox "No matches found for reservation #" & resNum
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Was thinking of an array at first too but its way too overkill. I got some more working for now tho see the edit